# Are any language bindings available for NSSpeechSynthesizer Cocoa class?

Tags: c++, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, text-to-speech, language-binding

I know that i can use PyObjC to access Cocoa objects in Python. Can i do this with C++? What other languages can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call objective C classes directly from Objective-C++ (.mm extension).  Objective-C++ allows you to mix C++ and Objective-C

Also from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29#Implementations):

> The Cocoa frameworks are written in Objective-C, and hence Objective-C
>   is the preferred language for
>   development of Cocoa applications.
>   Java bindings for the Cocoa frameworks
>   (known as the "Java bridge") are also
>   available but have not proven popular
>   amongst Cocoa developers. Further, the
>   need for runtime binding means many of
>   Cocoa's key features are not available
>   with Java. In 2005, Apple announced
>   that the Java bridge was to be
>   deprecated, meaning that features
>   added to Cocoa in Mac OS X versions
>   later than 10.4 would not be added to
>   the Cocoa-Java programming interface.
>       Originally, Applescript Studio could be used to develop less complex
>   Cocoa applications.[4] However, as of
>   Snow Leopard, it has been deprecated.
>   It was replaced with ApplescriptObjC,
>   which allows you to program in
>   Applescript, while using Cocoa
>   frameworks. [5]
>       Third-party bindings available for other languages include Clozure CL,
>   LispWorks, PyObjC (Python), RubyCocoa
>   (Ruby), CamelBones (Perl), Cocoa#,
>   Monobjc (C#) and NObjective(C#).[6] Nu
>   uses the Objective-C object model
>   directly, and therefore can use the
>   Cocoa frameworks without requiring a
>   binding.
>       There are also open source implementations of major parts of the
>   Cocoa framework that allows
>   cross-platform (including Microsoft
>   Windows) Cocoa application
>   development, such as GNUstep, and
>   Cocotron.